# acesso negado há base de dados mariadb no linux python3

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, python-3.x

boa tarde,
Eu estava fazendo um testes e resolvi tentar usar o python3 para manipular bases de dados porem eu nunca consigo conectar com a base dados com o python pois acontece sempre o mesmo erro:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Eu fiz a instalação completa da mariadb com o comando

```
sudo_mysql_secure_installation
```

Não sei se preciso de mais algum comando ou fazer mais alguma coisa.

O codigo que usei para conectar com o python3 é o seguinte:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",database="testes",user="root",passwd="hugo")
print(mydb)
```

Comment: Certifique-se de que a senha está correta e que a base "testes" realmente existe (não sei se isso ocasionaria um _access denied_, mas é bom verificar).

Comment: sim existe essa base de dados

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver com Python, o erro é que você não autorizou um usuário "root" com senha "hugo" para acessar o DB pelo caminho "localhost". Precisa verificar e corrigir isso diretamente com as ferramentas do DB, testar o acesso com estas ferramentas, certificando-se de que funciona, aí usa no Python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"print(mydb)" Aqui vc está tentando imprimir o objeto por isso o erro tenta dessa forma que deve dar certo.

```
import mysql.connector

(mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    database="testes",
    user="root",
    passwd="hugo"
    )

#Cria Um objeto Cursor
cursor = (mydb.cursor()
#execulta o comando mysql
cursor.execute('Select * from tabela')
#recebe o valor da consulta
myresult = cursor.fetchall()
for resultado in myresult:
    print (resultado[1],"-->", resultado[2]) # imprime o resultado
```